# Question about a theorem about branch of logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I've read a proof from Complex Made Simple (David C. Ullrich)

> **Proposition 4.3.** Suppose that $V$ is an open subset of the plane. There exists a branch of the logarithm in $V$ if and only if there exists $f \in H(V)$ with $f'(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ for all $z \in V$.

> **Proof**: One direction is trivial and the other is very easy: Suppose that $f \in H(V)$ and $f'(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ for all $z \in V$. Choose $z_0 \in V$. Note that $z_0 \ne 0$, so $z_0$ has a logarithm. Hence we can choose a constant $c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $e^{c+f(z_0)} = z_0$, and now $L$ is a branch of the logarithm in $V$, if $L(z) = c+f(z)$ for all $z \in V$.

I don't understand how we can choose that constant $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and how it is a branch of logarithm if we know that $e^{L(z)} = z$ only for $z = z_0$.

Thanks!

Comment: Since $z_0$ has a logarithm say $y_0$, i.e. $e^{y_0}=z_0$, then only need to set $c=y_0-f(z_0)$. And by direct calculation you know that the derivative of $e^{L(z)}/z$ is zero, which implies that $e^{L(z)}=z$ for $z$ in the same connection component of $z_0$.

Comment: @MikeMichael_maths this works for connected set $V$. But statement is for an open set.

Comment: @MikeMichael_maths if I take one $z_k$ from each connected component of $V$ and determine a $c_k$ and a function $L_k$ for each connected component where $k = \{1, 2, \ldots, \text{number of connected components}\}$ and in the end define a piecewise function on $V$, like $L(z) = L_1(z)$ if it is in the first connected component, $L(z) = L_2(z)$ if it's in the second connected component and so on.. it's ok?

Comment: I think the statement is incorrect and $V$ needs to be a domain (i.e. connected and open set) for this to work. Please if somebody  have some idea, let me know...